# Fortran 90 Presence Of Optional Arguments

Tags: fortran, optional-parameters, fortran90

I do not understand the behavior of the present() intrinsic function with pgf90 7.2.  I wrote a 20 line sample program to test this, but the results still make no sense to me.  Observe:

```
subroutine testopt(one,two,three,four,five)

  implicit none

  integer, intent(in) :: one,two
  integer, intent(out) :: three
  integer, intent(in), optional :: four
  integer, intent(out), optional :: five

  three = one + two

  print *,"present check: ",present(four),present(five)

  if (present(four) .and. present(five)) then

  five = four*four

end if

end subroutine testopt
```

if I: call testopt(1,2,(any variable)) from my main program, it prints: "present check: T F".  However if I: call testopt(1,2,(any variable)) from a subprogram it prints: "present check: T T".  I expected to see "present check: F F" in either case, because I am only calling the subroutine with the 3 non-optional arguments, and neither of the optional ones.  I cannot fathom why it would behave this way, and this is causing a major bug in a program I am working on.  I appreciate any insight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you placing this subroutine in a module and then having a "use" statement for that module in the calling routine (main program or subroutine)?   A typical rule is that many of the advanced / new features of Fortran 90 require an explicit interface so that both the caller and callee pass the arguments consistently.   The easiest and best way to accomplish this is with module / use.   Just a guess...

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Placing the procedure in a module gave me the anticipated response.  Thanks.

Comment: I was having a very similar problem and was able to solve it by placing an explicit interface declaration in the calling function. There's a week I'll never get back ...

Answer (score 1):

In Modern Fortran optional arguments must be declared as optional in the calling function (either through a module or an explicit interface). In Fortran 77 it was possible to simply leave out the last argument, if it was a scalar number, so optional arguments could be passed without extra declaration in the calling routine. This might not have been part of the Fortran standard, but it was a helpful feature provided by wise compiler implementations. Unfortunately, Modern Fortran killed this awesome feature.