# Fortran 90 function with no arguments?

Tags: function, fortran, fortran90

I would like to know whether I MUST provide arguments for a function in Fortran 90? Can I have a function that takes in no arguments, like in Java, e.g. `get()`, for example?

Comment: There are *two* questions here, and I am not sure what the real question is. The first is "Must all arguments to a function be specified?" and the second is, "Can I define a function that accepts no parameters?" (Java does not have "optional" parameters, tricks with variadic parameters or overloading aside.)

Comment: A function may have no arguments.  It may also have optional arguments.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121954/fortran-90-presence-of-optional-arguments for an example.

Comment: @M.S.B. If you answer this question then OP can accept your answer and this one will disappear from the list of unanswered questions, we can all move on with our lives :-)  Failing that I'll probably wander back in a day or two and vote to close just to tidy up the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  A function that takes no arguments is simply declared with no arguments, e.g.

```
integer function get_a_number()
   implicit none
   get_a_number = 42
end function get_a_number
```

which takes no arguments and simply returns the value 42 in default integer kind.

You can also have optional arguments, e.g.

```
function hello_string(name)
  implicit none
  character(len=150) :: hello_string
  character(len=*), optional :: name

  if (present(name)) then
     hello_string = "Hello "//trim(name)//"!"
  else
     hello_String = "Hello!"
  end if
end function
```

This function will return "Hello!" if called with no argument, and "Hello *name*!" if provided with an argument.  This function can take 1 or 0 arguments.  Note that this kind of function will require an explicit interface to work properly.